# How to refactor this code block to be simple and dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring, watermark

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.watermark').focus(function() {
        if (this.className == 'watermark')
        {
            this.className = '';
            this.value = '';
        }
    });

    $('.watermark').blur(function() {
        if (this.value == '')
        {
            this.className = 'watermark';
            this.value = 'Type here';
        }
    });
});
```

I have this block of code that works perfectly except that it is not dynamic. I was wondering if there was an elegant way to reset the value to the original dynamically. I was thinking that maybe if you defined the original text in its ID or some other sort of attribute you could reset it that way.. or maybe you could use variables or arrays or tuples. What does SO think is the best way of doing it?

Comment: My refactoring typically extends me [passing the code to google](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+watermark+plugin&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) and [seeing if](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/updnWatermark) i [have re-invented](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TinyWatermark) the [wheel](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about storing the value into some other attribute of the input?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.watermark').focus(function() {
        if (this.className == 'watermark')
        {
            this.className = '';
            this.title = this.value;
            this.value = '';
        }
    });

    $('.watermark').blur(function() {
        if (this.value == '')
        {
            this.className = 'watermark';
            this.value = this.title;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario i prefer to use html5([placeholder attrinute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute)) with javascript fall back.

```
function supports_input_placeholder() {
  var i = document.createElement('input');
  return 'placeholder' in i;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!supports_input_placeholder())
  {
    $('input').each(function(){
      $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
    });
    $('input').focus(function() {
        if (this.className == 'watermark')
        {
            this.className = '';
            this.value = '';
        }
    });

    $('input').blur(function() {
        if (this.value == '')
        {
            this.className = 'watermark';
            this.value = $(this).attr('placeholder');
        }
    });
  }

});
```

This script will detect if native placeholder is available if not it will take text from placeholder attribute and simulate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just store it in a variable if it's scoped to each element:

```
$(function() {
  $('.watermark').each(function() {
    var lead = $(this).val();
    $(this).focus(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == lead) $(this).val('');
    }).blur(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val(lead);
    });
  });
});
```